# How can I fully deploy my front end Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, deployment, vuetify.js, web-deployment

My site uses Vue, Bootstrap, and Vuetify. It works locally. I deployed it on Netlify and Heroku with the same result. `index.html` runs, but not Vue. Bootstrap failed.

Here are 2 methods of deploying Bootstrap that work locally and their links. Method 1 fails.

1. Import locally.

[Netlify](https://peaceful-kepler-4e567d.netlify.app/)

In `main.js`:

```
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

2. Import from a CDN.

[Netlify](https://nervous-archimedes-f78b5d.netlify.app/) [Heroku](https://skillportfolios.herokuapp.com/)

In `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Deployment steps:

- [For Heroku, I followed steps here with the below changes:](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#heroku)

Commands I used in step 3:

```
npm run build
git add .
git commit -m "deploy"
```

I added a name to the app in step 4.

- After deploying to Heroku, I had a `dist` folder directory. For Netlify, I dragged this to a box that said "Drag and drop your site folder here".

This is in `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

Michal Levý's answer worked. I set publicPath when following a tutorial.
I commented it out in `vue.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  // publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  //   ? '/skillportfolios/'
  //   : '/'
}
```

[I got it working here in Netlify](https://compassionate-saha-55c472.netlify.app/), but not Heroku. That's good enough.

Comment: Do not set [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) if your app is sitting at the web root ....

Comment: That worked. https://compassionate-saha-55c472.netlify.app/